# Regulate higher voltage for mcu and tracking pre-regulator

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, design, switching-regulator

I am currently designing a lab bench power supply using the [LT3080](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/3080fc.pdf). It will have an input of 18V and an output of 0-15V and 1A. I am going to use an Atmega328 to control the limits and a display. For that I of course need 5V and I am using a [LM2576](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2576.pdf?ts=1630375661945&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) to drop 18V to 8V and then using a [LM7805](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm340.pdf) to get a steady 5V output.
I also want to add a tracking pre-regulator to the LT3080 which will keep the input about 1V above the output.

Now the question is, how could I generate both the 5V and the voltage for the tracking pre-regulator while keeping the part-count low? Is there a good dual-output switcher that covers my voltages and currents, or is it better to use two individual switchers? Or is there even a better way than switchers?

EDIT:
I will use an ac-dc wall adapter to get the 18V DC input.

Comment: Using a multi tap transformer you get 9V and then with a LDO you get 5V, makes no sense to use a SMPS. The pre-regulator is made with a thyristor phase angle control and a large choke.

Comment: The input is DC so I don't know how I would use a transformer.

Comment: Usually a lab bench PSU is plugged into a mains 50/60Hz and it has a bulky and heavy transformer inside. Everything else is not a  linear bench PSU.